# MYSQL unknown column error on live server

Tags: java, mysql, database, servlets

From a servlet in Java I am calling a function to execute a query, Query is given below, I have tried these formats:

Error is:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column
>   'TFM00100' in 'field list'

Queries I have tried:

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl_contract AS tc   WHERE  tc.`contact_id` = 'TFM00100'    
 SELECT * FROM tbl_contract AS tc   WHERE  tc.`contact_id` = "TFM00100"    
 SELECT * FROM tbl_contract   WHERE  `contact_id` = 'TFM00100'    
 SELECT * FROM tbl_contract   WHERE  `contact_id` = "TFM00100"     
 SELECT * FROM tbl_contract   WHERE  contact_id = "TFM00100"     
 SELECT * FROM tbl_contract AS tc  WHERE (tc.`contact_id`  =  'TFM-00100');
```

I also have tried with prepared statement also.

But same error return when call specific function to execute a query from a servlet on live server, On local server it is working fine. Also when execute specific query on live MySQL db it works fine.

Servlet Relevent code only:

```
public class AttandenceInOutReport extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public AttandenceInOutReport() {
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    proccessRequest(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    proccessRequest(request, response);
}

protected void proccessRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    /**
     * Setting default response
     */
     // Rest of code

    try {
        /**
         * converting request into string
         */
        String res = WebServiceUtils.parseRequestToString(request);

        /**
         * Request write in logger
         */
        logger.info("Request from client" + res);

        AttandenceReportReq reportReq = new Gson().fromJson(res, AttandenceReportReq.class);

        if (reportReq != null && !reportReq.equals("") && (!WebServiceUtils.isEmpty(reportReq.getStartDate()))
                && (!WebServiceUtils.isEmpty(reportReq.getEndDate())) 
                && (!WebServiceUtils.isEmpty(reportReq.getContractId()))) {

            final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

            LocalDate startDate = formatter.parseLocalDate(reportReq.getStartDate());
            LocalDate endDate = formatter.parseLocalDate(reportReq.getEndDate());
            String contractId = reportReq.getContractId();

            //List<TblContract> contactList = new ArrayList<TblContract>();

            // Function being called here

            String contractName = CommonHandler.getContract(contractId);

           // Rest of the code
           // ...............

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        success = false;
        logger.error("Exception in processing request " + e);
    }

           // Rest of the code
           // ...............
    }
}
```

Function being called:

```
public static String getContractName(String conId) {

    Connection conn = (Connection) DBConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String contractName = "";

    String query =  "SELECT contract_name FROM tbl_contract WHERE contact_id = '" + conId + "' ";

    try {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()) {    
            contractName = rs.getString("contract_name");   
        }

   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return contractName;   
   } finally {
       if (conn != null) {    
       try {
           rs.close();
           pstmt.close();
           conn.close();    
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return contractName;
       }
   }
  }
    return contractName; 
}
```

Comment: Can you share `servlet` code for same?

Comment: did you check your default database? maybe you are using a different database. try using  `database_name.table_name`.

Comment: @dranrebdino if there is default database ,even though it will not give error for `Unknown column 'TFM00100' in 'field `.

Comment: can post ur code please?

Comment: @SagarGangwal i'm assuming he a dummy database with the same tables but not data because sometimes, errors comes from little details.

Comment: Besides the servlet's code (which is a must), the full `create table` statement for `tbl_contract` would be useful.

Comment: Function and servlet code added.  Table create statement can not post here: for understanding contract_id is varchar(100) and contract_name is varchar(250) values are ('TFM00100','contract one')

Comment: Guys it is really strange error, some progress toward solution is: If column value is in lower case like ('123456','contract one')  ('abcdef','contract one') than it works fine. if contract_id value is in UPPER case than it throws error. Why this is the case, totally shocked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
   String query =  "SELECT contract_name FROM tbl_contract WHERE contact_id = ? ";

    try {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, conId);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: I have tried this one. Found a solution when apply conId.trim() than work some time.